# How to create a new point and line?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm very new in this field and lack of knowledge in coding. I need to create a new point and line in my coding and then combine it with each other. It's possible that this Optical Flow Lucas Kanade method can make a coding in emgucv C#? I need used this method to make a coding.

Comment: i have already display an image in my coding. In my question, i need to make a certain point  and combine it with a line in that image. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio C# WPF application.

Comment: Please post that code, as the question is written now it is very difficult to tell what you are asking